# If else use "not in" in list comprehension python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I wanted to understand the motive why this kind of formula works if I use this code:

```
a = [2,4,6,8]
b = [2,5,6,9]

list_same = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] in b]
list_dif = [b[i] for i in range(len(a)) if b[i] not in a] 
list_dif1 = [lista_dif.append(a[i]) for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] not in b]
```

and doesn't work if I use this other code:

```
list_dif = [b[i] if b[i] not in a 
                else a[i] if a[i] not in b
                for i in range(len(a))]
```

Would anyone be able to tell me where the error is?
Thanks

Comment: The first one is filtering the list comprehension, adding a value only if it passes the test. The second one *always* adds a value, you’re just determining what value with an `..if..else..` expression.

Comment: you really should use sets for this

Comment: It would help if you explained exactly what you mean by "this one works" and "this one doesn't work".

Comment: You are trying to nest two conditional *expressions* (which have little to do with the list comprehension), and the nested expression is lacking its `else` portion.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but have deleted. Your code is odd and erroring, and that's a bigger problem then answering why they are different. Your second "different" example doesn't run without error. Please provide a minimal reproducible example and share what two variables you are comparing.

Comment: Jean-François Fabre yes I know the sets very well, but I wanted to understand why this code does not work

Comment: Chepner, could you tell me where, because I can't figure out where it's missing

Comment: JNevi look that the first code works perfectly. it's the second one that doesn't do what it's supposed to do. On the second one I would like to understand why

Answer (score 2):

Conditional expressions always require an "if" part and an "else" part:

```
V1 if C else V2
```

In your code, you are using another conditional expression for `V2`, but you omitted the `else` portion.

```
V1 if C1 else (V2 if C2 else V3)
```

(The parentheses may be dropped, but I've used them here for clarity. YOur code reads `V1 if C1 else V2 if C2`, missing `else V3`.) You must specify a value to use if both `C1` and `C2` are false.

Further, do not confuse the filter portion of the list comprehension with a conditional expression. Aside from the shared use of the `if` keyword, they have little to nothing in common.

Comment: The problem is that there is no third opition

Comment: If there is no third option, you cannot use a conditional expression. The list comprehension *must* have something to add to the list for every value from the generator *not* filtered by the final `if` clause.

Comment: chepner ok thanks, now I understand